# Is there any elevator between the first floor (car rental) and second floor (departure area) in Asuncion airport (Silvio Pettirossi airport, ASU)?

Tags: airports, accessibility, paraguay, asuncion, asu

Is there any elevator between the first floor (car rental) and second floor (departure area) in Asuncion airport ([Silvio Pettirossi International Airport, ASU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvio_Pettirossi_International_Airport))?

I couldn't find any airport map on https://www.asuncion-airport.com

Comment: Downvoter: elevators are critical for people needing to use wheelchairs or luggage trolleys. Please explain the downvote.